# On monomial ideals and ring generated by monomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

Question 1: Is $(x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4)$ a maximal ideal in $\mathbb C [ x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4] $?

Question 2: Are the ideals $(x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4)$ and $(x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4)$ distinct in the ring $\mathbb C[x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4] $ ?

If the answer to both the questions is yes, then we get an example of ideals $I,J$ in a domain $R$ such that $I$ is maximal, $J\ne I$ and $I^2=J^2$.

Comment: If you look for such an example, then $R=\mathbb C[x^3,x^5,x^7]$ seems to be another candidate. Set $I=(x^3,x^5,x^7)$ and $J=(x^3,x^5)$.

Comment: And if you want R to be a local domain then take power series instead of polynomials in the above example, or localize at the maximal ideal I.

Comment: Great! You found the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: It is the kernel of the restriction of the surjective ring homomorphism
$$\Bbb{C}[x,y]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}:\ f(x,y)\ \longmapsto\ f(0,0),$$
to the ring $\Bbb{C}[x^4,x^3y,x^2y^2,xy^3,y^4]$, so it is maximal.

Question 2: Of course; the latter clearly does not contain $x^2y^2$.

Comment: In your second map, where do you send $x^2y^2$ to ? Itself ?

Comment: Yes; it remains to verify that this is indeed a ring homomorphism. Come to think of it, it is easier to just note that the latter ideal does not contain $x^2y^2$. I have edited accordingly.